# Can we declare sealed method in a class

Tags: c#, oop, overriding, sealed

```
class X {
    sealed protected virtual void F() {
        Console.WriteLine("X.F");
    }
    sealed void F1();
    protected virtual void F2() {
        Console.WriteLine("X.F2");
    }
}
```

In the above code there is compile time error :

> X.F()' cannot be sealed because it is not an override
>
> X.F1()' cannot be sealed because it is not an override

Does it mean we can only apply the `sealed` keyword whey we have to override some methods?

Comment: The MSDN entry for [sealed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/88c54tsw.aspx) seems pretty clear. Sealing a virtual method does not make sense (why make it virtual and then prevent overriding?). And sealing a "normal" method also does not make sense, since by default you can't override it anyway. That leaves the scenario that you want (and do) override a method but say "anything inheriting from me must not override this method any further". That's what `sealed override` is for.

Comment: What is it that you want to do with this code? Maybe there's a different way to accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, *sealed* keyword prevents method from being *overriden*, and that's why it doesn't make sence

1. with *virtual* declaration - just remove `virtual` instead of declaring `virtual sealed`.
2. on *abstract* methods, since abstract methods must be overriden
3. on *non-virtual* methods, since these methods just can't be overriden

So the only option is `override sealed` which means *override, but the last time*:

```
public class A {
  public virtual void SomeMethod() {;}

  public virtual void SomeOtherMethod() {;}
}

public class B: A {
  // Do not override this method any more
  public override sealed void SomeMethod() {;}

  public override void SomeOtherMethod() {;}
}

public class C: B {
  // You can't override SomeMethod, since it declared as "sealed" in the base class
  // public override void SomeMethod() {;}

  // But you can override SomeOtherMethod() if you want
  public override void SomeOtherMethod() {;}
}
```